# email parsing inline attachment

Tags: python, email, parsing

I'm creating a python script to parse the content of various emails, they don't have the same layout etc.
For now, what I do is the following:

```
 if msg.is_multipart():
     for part in msg.walk():
         base = ""
         if (part.is_attachment()):
             payload = part.get_payload()
             for elem in payload:
                 base+=str(elem)
             withattachment = "yes"
             name = part.get_filename()
             base=base.replace("\n","")
 else:
     base = None
     if (msg.is_attachment()):
         withattachment = "yes"
         name = msg.get_filename()
         base =msg.get_payload()
```

The "base" variable contains the base64 of the attachment.
I need to do the same for the inline attachments, but afaik there's no .isinline() function to check it. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: The indentation of this code is incorrect: does the last `else`match the opening `if` or the `for`?

Comment: Sorry I'll fix it now, got incorrect when I pasted it. It's the else for the "If msg.is_multipart()"

Comment: I've revised it to be correct. You will find great benefit in ensuring that your own code is correctly and consistently indented.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the method email.iter_attachments()

Comment: How you parse the mails ? I try use the method `iter_attachments()` but shows me an error that method not exists...